# Distribution of players in a computer game on different "levels"

Tags: distributions, references, experiment-design, stochastic-processes, games

Many computer games have different levels. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_(video_games)) is a description about levels on wikipedia, but I will explain more precisely what I mean below.

The idea is this: to optimize the experience with a game played online between two or more people, we need to try our best to make sure that people with comparable experiences/skills play the game together. To achieve this, one very simple way is to set different "levels" of the game, and move one to a higher level if he or she wins a lot at a lower level. Another way of achieving this is to use a virtual system of "money", as an indicator of players' strength and experience. In any event, we will end up with a distribution of players on different levels or with different "wealth".

Are there any theory which discusses such distributions, and the implications on whether this is good/bad for player experiences?

Also, what are some existing example of this type of statistical data? **EDIT:** This is not asking for data sets. This is just asking for a place where this theory can be useful.

It would help a lot if anyone could give a reference. This is of course not limited to computer games, but any other similar games.

Comment: These are interesting questions but they seem to be a matter for those who study such games, rather than for statistics to answer.

Comment: @whuber Notice that I have mentioned distributions, which is what statistics is about. Games involve statistics.

Comment: *Everything* involves statistics.  That doesn't make everything on topic here.

Comment: @whuber There are other questions about games and scores on this site. Please explain why.

Comment: You aren't asking a statistical question: you seek data sets, something that is explicitly off-topic here.  This suggests the other questions you might be trying to ask are also off topic.  In particular, statistics offers little insight into what those distributions might be: that is a matter for empirical investigation.

Comment: @whuber This is clearly NOT about data sets, but about models for distributions that can be written as an mathematical expression.

Comment: @whuber You should see the word "THEORY" very clearly.

Comment: Given the original post was vague, your repeated use of "clearly" *after* editing it is, at best, disingenuous.

Comment: @whuber If the original question is vague, how can you be sure it is about data sets?

Comment: And how can you be sure that there are "little insights"?

Comment: @whuber It is clear even before edit. There is nothing wrong with making it more clear by an edit. "Existing statistical data" ask for a general example, not necessarily a set of data. I remind you to use words such as "disingenuous" cautiously.

Comment: I did say the word, "THEORY", at the first place.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Elo rating system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) (originally developed for chess) and Microsoft's [TrueSkill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueSkill) system (used for video games)

Comment: @user20160 Thank you for the links.

Comment: @MaJoad from real-world data sets, your question doesn't have a unique answer.  The actual income distributions around the world, especially when conditioned upon things like occupation range from the normal distribution in places with strong unions, to Levy distributions without a mean or a variance.  The rules in the society seem to determine the distributions involved.  Unfortunately, as it is likely nobody has played the game you are looking at, you will probably have to play the game to figure it out.

Comment: @MaJoad you should probably ask this question in the economics forum.  If you get lucky and find a labor economist, you might get lucky, though most don't care about the distributions in the way you are thinking about it.